# calling a function from a function object in python

Tags: python, function, object, oop, dereference

**how to call a function from a function object**

```
a = fun_name
print(a)
```

like from this function object that I get how can I call the original function only from using this function object

```
<function fun_name at 0x00000265C9B0E320>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just call the object, since it's just a function object, not really but it refers to it, example:

```
def a():

    return 'a'

b = a
print(b())
```

Comment: actually I'm storing this in a dictionary

Comment: dct = {"func": func}

Comment: now i want dct["func"] to call the function func but it's giving me a function object can i call that object to call my original function

Comment: Just do this: dct['func']()

Answer (score 1):

You can call the original function like `a()` in this case.

Comment: thanks, it was simple though but still, I wasn't able to figure it out  !!!